# Core Data saving an existing variable, like double and reload them

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm a beginner with Core Data. I have the following code and try to save an existing variable, in this case a double. This variable will increase by 10 every time when push the button (Action Button).
When I open the simulator the variable increases by 10 and the value is displayed in the label. Until here everything is fine, but when I restart the App then the variable is not saved.
Could you please point me out what I'm doing wrong? Or is there an easier way to save and reload (fetch) an existing variable?
I´ve created a Core Data Project with:

```
Entities: Statsohs (Codegen: Class Definition)
Attributs: value -> Type: Double
```

In AppDelegate there is all the code for Core-Data stack and Core-Data saving support:

---

Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    //  Reference to Managed Object Context
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    //    Data for the Stats
      var Avg : [Statsohs]?

    var number : Double = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelStats: UILabel!
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        fetchStats()
        
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @IBAction func ActionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        number = number + 10
        
        let average = Statsohs(context: self.context)
        average.value = number
        
        LabelStats.text = String(format: "%.2f", average.value)
        
        //Save the data
                        do {
                            try context.save()
                            
                        }
                        catch {
                            
                        }
        
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func fetchStats() {
                
                //Fetch the data from CoreData to display in the View

                do {
                    self.Avg = try context.fetch(Statsohs.fetchRequest())
                    
                    
                }
                catch {
                    
                }
            }
    
}
```

---

I tried different code ways, but no one works. That was for me looking the easiest, but unfortunately with no success.
I expected that `average.value` was saved and after reloading the app was showing on the simulator. But unfortunately not.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please respect the Swift naming convention that functions/methods and variables start with a lowercase letter. In `fetchStats` you fetch the data but the code to display the value(s) is missing. Consider that every time you press the button a new record is inserted. And when you launch the app `value` starts always with zero. And why is `Avg` optional?

Comment: There is no SwiftUI here

Comment: You are creating a new object each time you want to save an increase in `number` which I assume is wrong. You want to update the same Statsohs object instead. So maybe have a property `var average: Statsohs` instead of the `number` property?

Comment: Dear @vadian,
thank you for your feedback. I understood what the problem is, but not know how to fix it. You wrote that in `fetchStats` the code to display the value(s) is missing. How the code at `fetchStats` (or other elsewhere) must look like, that value is updated each time when press the button and display it?

Is it better to write Avg like: var Avg : [Statsohs] = []?

Comment: @jnpdx - sorry for the mistake

Comment: Dear @JoakimDanielson
thank you for your feedback.
Right, each time when the button is pressed I want to update Statsohs instead. 
I tried to create: var average = Statsohs() (directly under were I created var number)
Then in Action button:
average = Statsohs(context: self.context)
average.value = number
and so on, but I will get the error Message: 
CoreData: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Statsohs'

Comment: To be more exact, you need to declare the property as optional since it will not have an initial value. So `var average: Statsohs?`. Then you need to figure out how to assign a value to it and where to do that in your code. If the whole idea is to have only one instance of the object persisted, then selected the first one from the fetch result or if that is empty create a new one instead.

Comment: As you (@JoakimDanielson) said I created: var average: Statsohs?
Then: In Action Button: average = Statsohs(context: self. context)
average?.value = number
LabelStats.text = String(format: "%.2f", average!.value)
In func fetchStats: self.average = try context.fetch(Statsohs.fetchRequest()) -> In this line I get the error message: Cannot assign value of type '[Statsohs]' to type 'Statsohs'. What is the exact declaration?